# How to find which day of the week it is java

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, dayofweek

I want to find the day of the week in java without the use of date and other methods that do it on theirselves.I can find the daydifference between 2 dates but I cant understand how I can find which day of the week that specific date is.

Comment: Have you tried using `Calendar`?

Comment: Why would you want to reinvent the wheel? And what time zone are you interested in? Date and time is complex - you should *absolutely* avoid doing the calculations yourself unless you have a *really* good reason to do so.

Comment: Sounds like an assignment I had to do when I was studying computer science. There is a formular to calculate the day of the week...

Comment: Show us what you have done.... and we will point you further...

Comment: I have a good reason to not use calendar date and things like that.They are prohibited because it's an assignment.I dont care about the time zone.Time doesnt count just days ,months,years

Comment: You *must* care about time zone - because if two people are in different time zones, they may well observe different dates. Currently it's a Sunday in my time zone - but it's already Monday in Australia. Note that in future, if you're going to give odd requirements, you should state the reasons for them to start with, instead of us having to drag them out of you. Is there anything else important that you haven't told us?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Maybe in his task time zones doesn't count. In other words: The question is bad formulated

Comment: I dont know what time zone it is here it's 19:40 atm.I cant show you it's huge....this is a piece
  println("");
  println("For the date the day was "+daydifference1%7);
  println("(0=Monday,1=Tuesday,.....6=Sunday)");

Comment: Given a calendar date (i.e. "5 Nov 2012" - not a `java.util.Date` object), then the timezone *doesn't* matter, surely? (Assuming one is working in the Gregorian Calendar regardless). It *does* matter if the input is a `java.util.Date`, but that's not the question.

Comment: Uhm no I dont want you to do my homework I have tried 5 days now to find something out my homework is due today so I thought I could use some help....

Comment: You can't show us yours code, because it's too big? Edit your post and print it there please. Not in a comment.

Comment: Note that, if this was NOT an assignment and you're not actually building a library for reuse, doing any of the computations described here will win you enemies. Time calculations are exceedingly complex and have lots of edge cases; much better to leverage an existing, well-tested, actively maintained library than to try writing it yourself.

Comment: I said this is an assignment in a comment above.So I cant use a library.

Comment: Ok, I looked at your code. Unfortunately the approach you're using will not work. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find the day difference between two days, then just use the mod operator.

For instance, if you know that `day1 = Monday`, and you want to find which day it is after 701 days, it is `Monday + 701 % 7 = Monday + 1 = Tuesday`.

Comment: I know the day difference and monday=0.but if the day is sunday I have to deduct -2 and I cant possibly know when I have to deduct and when I have to add

Comment: Choose a base day, and calculate the difference of a specific date with this base day. The difference is either positive or negative, you do not have to consider anything else. A negative difference handles what you are asking for.

Comment: but the modulo7 gives out a result of 2 if they day is sunday so I would have to deduct that but if it's tuesday it still shows 2.

Comment: What you are saying does not make sense. You should post some code.

Answer (score 1):

There are formulas for figuring out what day of the week a particular day is on:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Purely_mathematical_methods

Answer (score 0):

The approach you've chosen seems extremely complicated and error prone.

I suggest creating your own class named *Date*.

A date will contain a month, day, and year and will know how to subtract or add days.

It should also be able to determine if it is equal to, before, or after another date.

You should use an array of ints to represent the number of days in each month.

This array can be a private static field of your Date class.

Then you can create an instance of your class that represents date2 and subtract one day at a time until it equals date1.

You can use a similar approach to determine the day of the week by comparing the input dates to a base date with a known day of week.

I'm certain this is what your instructor intended for this assignment.

This will teach you a valuable lesson:

Take advantage of objects to use encapsulation in stead of using a bunch of *if statements*.

Comment: I said already I have chosen a date which is 31/8/2020 because it's monday